# Less or equal to in jquery.validationEngine.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form and am using `jquery.validationEngine.js` for validation:

```
  var isValid = $("#my-forma").validationEngine('validate');
```

In the form there're inputs text. How can I ensure that one has a numeric value less or equal to 10?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support [IE 8 and less](http://caniuse.com/#search=number) you can use HTML 5 for your input, it will look like this:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="10" />
```

And if you still want to use your jquery plugin (which is not the best one). I found this in their documentation

> **min[float]**
>
> Validates when the field's value is less than, or equal to, the given parameter.
>
> **max[float]**
>
> Validates when the field's value is more than, or equal to, the given parameter.

[Reference here](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#minfloat)

Comment: yes, but how exactly should I use min[float] and max[float]?